# Accessing SQL Database Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple database of messages and users. Messages holds id, message and date of creation. I'm trying to put those into the data base after the person hits submit on the message but I'm getting a few issues by it giving me 0 everytime for the id no matter who inputs, and 0-0-0 for date of creation.
The two files of code that I'm working with is this.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    include "validate.php";
    include "src/header.php";
    include "src/mainmenu.php";
?>
    <form method="post" action="message_action.php">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Message Area</legend>
    <p>
        <label for="message">Message:</label> <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>

    <p class="center"><input value="Send" type="submit" /></p>
    </fieldset>
    </form>

    <p><a href="exit.php">Exit</a></p>
<?php   
    include "src/footer.php";
?>
```

---

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include 'db.php';

    $id_user = $_SESSION['id']; 
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO messages (id_user, message) VALUES ('$id_user','$message');";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    mysqli_close($link);

    if ($result == false) {
        include "src/header.php";
        include "src/mainmenu.php";
        echo '<p>Error: cannot execute query</p>';
        echo '<p><a href="register.php">Try again</a></p>';
        include "src/footer.php";
        exit;
    }
    else {
        header('Location: private.php');
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Date Of creation now works, but still an issue with getting the id_user.

Database

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.5
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Servidor: localhost:33306
-- Tiempo de generación: 31-05-2012 a las 09:56:35
-- Versión del servidor: 5.5.16
-- Versión de PHP: 5.3.8

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `minifacebook`
--
CREATE DATABASE `minifacebook2` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `minifacebook2`;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `messages`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `date_of_creation` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `info` text NOT NULL,
  `date_of_birth` date NOT NULL,
  `place_of_birth` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `date_of_reg` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `nationality` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `friend` int(3),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=23 ;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: You don't have form elements `id_user` or `date_of_creation`, so `$_POST['id_user']` and `$_POST['date_of_creation']` do not exist, so they default to `0`. You either need to add these to the form, or you can set them in the php -> `$id_user = $_SESSION['userid']; $date_of_creation = date('Y-m-d');`

Comment: Can you provide more information on how your application works? Database schemas, etc? Where is the `id_user` value generated?

Comment: Sure, I added the database. And the id_user I'm not sure how its supposed to be associated with the person, as the person is already logged in at this point.

Comment: @Sean. The date of creation fixed it, but I don't have a userid in my users database to correlate.

Comment: The `$_SESSION['userid']` was a guess, as it was before you provided any information (pre 1st edit). Are you storing the logged-in user data in a session? If so, it could be `$_SESSION['id']`. Basically however you would get `\`users\`.\`id\``.

Comment: @Sean. Yes, they are stored in a session. Should I put session_start() in the message_action.php for it to be able to grab the id?

Comment: Just a remark, you dont need to put value $date_of_creation in your INSERT query as you already have DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for date_of_reg

Comment: Yes, you would need to add `session_start()` and then you could use the logged-in users info, namely their `id`.

Comment: @Suenda. Oh wow, thanks! I'll just remove that from the line then.

Comment: @Sean. Ok I added it but it still gives me a zero as the id. $id_user= $_SESSION['id'];. Is this the correct format?

Comment: What is in your `$_SESSION` array? Try doing `print_r($_SESSION)` to see if you even stored the logged-in users `id`. If not, you will need to change your log in script to save the `id` in `$_SESSION` or query your user table again to get it before doing your `INSERT`.

Comment: @Sean. Ahh Okay, Its only storing if the log-in was validated and the user name. Okay I'll try to add it to the array.

Comment: @Sean. Okay that seemed to work. Would you happen to know how to join both tables so if I was connected to the users table, I could still look up their messages?

Comment: So you want to join `users` and `messages` to get all the messages from a specific user? ie. `SELECT u.*, m.* FROM \`users\` u LEFT JOIN \`messages\` m ON u.id = m.user_id WHERE u.id = userIDthatYOUwant`

Comment: @Sean. Correct. I'm just having a hard time reading your line. U stands for users? and m for messages? Does the u.* stay as is or was that just short hand?

Comment: the `u` and `m` are aliases. Aliases are used in mysql so you don't have to keep writing the full table name over again each time. So `SELECT u.* FROM \`users\` u` is the same as `SELECT \`users\`.* FROM \`users\`` and the `*` means all columns (or you could specify the columns -> `u.id,u.name`)

Comment: @Sean. Alright, thank you so much for the help! I truly am grateful!